# What to do to ensure that values from Tkinter form is being entered into MySQL table instead of getting an error message?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, mysql-python, tkinter-entry

I've made a tkinter form that's supposed to enter values into a MySQL table. However, when i enter the appropriate values int the form, I get the error message created by me ("All fields are required"). In the following code, a=task_name.get() [string],     b=student_subject.get() [string], c=due_date.get() [int], d=priority.get() [int],     e=task_type.get() [string], and f=date_added.get() [int].

```
def action():

        if a=="" or b=="" or e=="":
            messagebox.showerror("Error" , "All fields are required" , parent = wintask)
        else:
            con = mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="12345678", database="ibcomputerscience")
            cur = con.cursor()
            cur.execute("INSERT INTO task_info(student_subject, task_name, due_date, priority, task_type, date_added) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(a, b, c, d, e, f))
            con.commit()
            con.close()
            messagebox.showerror("Success" , "Task Added Successfully", parent = wintask)
```

I'll appreciate any help/insight. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also have you tried printing out `a`, `b`, `c`, ...? Are they what you expect?

Comment: According to the code, if you get the mentioned error, it is obvious that either `a` or `b` or `e` is empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call those `.get()` inside `action()`:

```py
def action():
    a = student_subject.get()
    b = task_name.get()
    c = due_date.get()
    d = priority.get()
    e = task_type.get()
    f = date_added.get()

    if a == "" or b == "" or e == "":
        messagebox.showerror("Error", "All fields are required", parent=wintask)
    else:
        con = mysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="12345678", database="ibcomputerscience")
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO task_info(student_subject, task_name, due_date, priority, task_type, date_added) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",(a, b, c, d, e, f))
        con.commit()
        con.close()
        messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Task Added Successfully", parent=wintask)
```